# Настройка интернет-соединения на гостевой ОС через proxy

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, proxy, virtualbox

**Имеется**:
Virtual Box
Основная ОС Windows 7 - доступ в интернет через HTTP прокси

**Проблема:** не работает интернет в гостевой ОС. При этом, через терминал все сайты пингуются, но пакеты не устанавливаются. Так же не открываются страницы в браузере.

**Что я пробовал сделать:**

1. В Virtual Box "Файл - Настройки - Прокси - Прописал адрес"
2. Экспериментировал с различными вариантами настройки адаптеров сети в Virtual Box для гостевой ОС. Пока остановился на: 
   Сетевой адаптер: NAT
   Тип адаптера: Паравиртуальная сеть
3. В самой гостевой ОС пробовал через UI прописывать "Параметры - Сеть - Сетевой прокси"
4. Пробовал в настройках браузера устанавливать прокси

**Результат везде один:** Всё пингуется, но интернет не работает.
При всем этом, если например в основной ОС подключиться через обычную сеть (без прокси) - то в гостевой всё сразу начинает работать!

**С чем это может быть связано и как диагностировать причину проблемы?)**

Comment: В чём проблема сделать сетевой мост и в госте прописать те же настройки прокси, что и в хосте?

Comment: По какой-то причине так не работает

Comment: Значит у тебя прям вообще всё плохо, потому что у меня на работе тоже прокся и схема `мост + прокси в госте` работает отлично.

Comment: Проксю контролируешь?

Comment: Каким образом её контролить?

Comment: Ну ты настраивал прокси или админ вашей организации?